# Paw base Oauth encoding

Tags: paw-app

I am trying to do oauth 2 with Paw.  It doesn't appear to be encoding my Client ID and Client Secret correctly. My server expects username:password format. I have tried it in the same field, separate, with same results.

Example

Input = VjE6MHJ:SjZvR24=

Base 64 encode result = `VmpFNk1ISjpTalp2UjI0PQ==

Paw result = VmpFNk1ISjpTalp2UjI0JTNE

The base 64 result works and returns a token, but Paw does not as it is encoded wrong.

Answer (score 0):

It's a late answer, sorry! It seems like the only difference is that the `=` sign at the end of your password, is URL encoded by Paw, while your server doesn't expects a URL encoded value.

According to the [OAuth 2 spec / 2.3.1. Client Password](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-2.3.1), we need to URL encode the Client ID and Client Secret. Then the question is, should we also encode the `=` sign? It's not very clear from the spec. Have you tested with other clients (maybe client implementation of OAuth, in JS/Swift/Python/Java)?

Comment: It does work in php.  I encode the ID and secret individually, then encode the whole string "id:secret".  I would really like to get it to work with paw, so I can use the other features. I have tried putting the raw ID and Secret without encoding as well.  I get the error in the console, and it just seems to be encoding the string wrong.

Comment: Using curl with php and works.  (I wasn't specific above) Really don't understand how PAW encodes.  Does it encode the ID and Secret individually, then combine as ID:Secret and encode again?

Comment: The base64 we're using is pretty standard. Of course we first combine the strings together `ID:Secret`, then we compute the Base64 of the whole thing.

Comment: Why would paw show a different encoded result than encoding it by php?  The php encode works, but when paw encodes it the console shows the encoded credentials being sent is different.

Comment: I believe we're using a standard encoding, there's no reason to have this differently. Do you have a public endpoint you can share with us? Email us at support@luckymarmot.com if needed. Thanks!